# Is it ok to use const everywhere?

Tags: flutter

I heard that const variable will not dispose easily.

So, is it ok to always create widgets as const if it can, even when that widget use only once? Is it consume much memory if there're many const?

For examples, I create all screen as const.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: Home.routeName,
      routes: {
        AuthScreen.routeName: (context) => const AuthScreen(),
        Home.routeName: (context) => const Home(),
        OrderScreen.routeName: (context) => const OrderScreen(),
        EmailLoginScreen.routeName:(context) => const EmailLoginScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is useful when a widget does not need to be rebuilded because when a change is applied to one widget with setState the whole widget tree is rebuild, when const is used it will make your code faster...

Comment: I know what const do, but is it any problem to make too many const?

Comment: Its opposite. const is "compile-time constant", which means compiler already know that value.

Comment: `const` objects will live forever.  However, since they must be compile-time constants, there can be only a finite number of them, and unless you do something terrible with code generation, that number will be limited by practical constraints.  Therefore it usually isn't much of a concern in practice.  If you're still unsatisfied, you always can do memory profiling to see how much of an effect they have on memory in your own app.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have another question, VScode suggest me to always use const when can. Should I follow?

Comment: As I said, most of the time you shouldn't need to be concerned about the memory usage.  The advantages of using `const` therefore usually would outweigh the disadvantages, and you might as well use it where you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Widget tree rebuilds everytime a certain widget changes state. The consequence is that memory will be used a lot and some frames skipped. If you're sure some widgets don't need to change, place then as const. This way, they will not be refreshed and speed up the app in the process. As a simple rule, set const all  variables, fields, widgets that will not change values once assigned to them.